# blueimp - multiple uploader : error with no reason

Tags: jquery, image, upload, blueimp

I've followed the instruction of working with DB from this link : https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Working-with-databases. I checked everything especially for the connection settings. They're correct. But it keep displays "Error {}". I tried to find the clues on my server's log file and debugging tool but no chance of luck.

Here is the shapshot :

[image]

index.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$sid=$_GET['sid'];
$caption=$_GET['title'];
$view="0";
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
```

Moreover, I also attached the "UploadHandler.php" along to see if there's any hidden errors.

```
<?php

function __construct($options = null, $initialize = true, $error_messages = null) {
    $this->options = array(
        // mysql connection settings  
        'database' => '****',  
        'host' => 'localhost',  
        'username' => '****',  
        'password' => '****',  
        // end
        'script_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/',
        'upload_dir' => dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/files/',
        'upload_url' => $this->get_full_url().'/files/',
        'user_dirs' => false,
        'mkdir_mode' => 0755,
        'param_name' => 'files',
        // Set the following option to 'POST', if your server does not support
        // DELETE requests. This is a parameter sent to the client:
        'delete_type' => 'DELETE',
        'access_control_allow_origin' => '*',
        'access_control_allow_credentials' => false,
        'access_control_allow_methods' => array(
            'OPTIONS',
            'HEAD',
            'GET',
            'POST',
            'PUT',
            'PATCH',
            'DELETE'
        ),
        'access_control_allow_headers' => array(
            'Content-Type',
            'Content-Range',
            'Content-Disposition'
        ),
        .
.
.
.
.
I remain these lines untouched
.
.
.

protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
        $index = null, $content_range = null) {
    $file = new stdClass();
    $file->name = $this->get_file_name($name, $type, $index, $content_range);
    $file->size = $this->fix_integer_overflow(intval($size));
    $file->type = $type;
    if ($this->validate($uploaded_file, $file, $error, $index)) {
        $clientid = $this->handle_form_clientid($file, $index);
        $postid = $this->handle_form_postid($file, $index);
        //Add the call to the database to add the data. Notice the three variables
        //which are passed to the add_img function.           
        $this->add_img($file->name,$clientid,$postid);
        //End of our additions. The code continues...
        $upload_dir = $this->get_upload_path();
        if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
            mkdir($upload_dir, $this->options['mkdir_mode'], true);
        }
        $file_path = $this->get_upload_path($file->name);
        $append_file = $content_range && is_file($file_path) &&
            $file->size > $this->get_file_size($file_path);
        if ($uploaded_file && is_uploaded_file($uploaded_file)) {
            // multipart/formdata uploads (POST method uploads)
            if ($append_file) {
                file_put_contents(
                    $file_path,
                    fopen($uploaded_file, 'r'),
                    FILE_APPEND
                );
            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($uploaded_file, $file_path);
            }
        } else {
            // Non-multipart uploads (PUT method support)
            file_put_contents(
                $file_path,
                fopen('php://input', 'r'),
                $append_file ? FILE_APPEND : 0
            );
        }
        $file_size = $this->get_file_size($file_path, $append_file);
        if ($file_size === $file->size) {
            $file->url = $this->get_download_url($file->name);
            list($img_width, $img_height) = @getimagesize($file_path);
            if (is_int($img_width) &&
                    preg_match($this->options['inline_file_types'], $file->name)) {
                $this->handle_image_file($file_path, $file);
            }
        } else {
            //$file->size = $file_size;
            $file->upload_to_db = $this->add_img($sid,$file->name);
            if (!$content_range && $this->options['discard_aborted_uploads']) {
                unlink($file_path);
                $file->error = 'abort';
            }
        }
        $this->set_additional_file_properties($file);
    }
    return $file;
}
function query($query) {

$database = $this->options['database'];

$host = $this->options['host'];

$username = $this->options['username'];

$password = $this->options['password'];

$link = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);

if (!$link) {

die(mysql_error());

}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database);

if (!$db_selected) {

die(mysql_error());

}

$result = mysql_query($query);

mysql_close($link);

return $result;

}

function add_img($sid,$whichimg,$caption,$view){

$add_to_db = $this->query("INSERT INTO gallery_pix (galx_sid,galx_file,galx_cap,galx_view) VALUES
('$sid','$whichimg','$caption','$view')") or die(mysql_error());

return $add_to_db;

}

function delete_img($delimg){

$delete_from_db = $this->query("DELETE FROM gallery_pix WHERE galx_sid='$delimg'") or die(mysql_error());

return $delete_from_db;

}
.
.
.
These lines remain untouched
.
.
.




public function delete($print_response = true) {
    $file_name = $this->get_file_name_param();
    $file_path = $this->get_upload_path($file_name);
    $success = is_file($file_path) && $file_name[0] !== '.' && unlink($file_path);
    if ($success) {
        foreach($this->options['image_versions'] as $version => $options) {
            if (!empty($version)) {                 
                $file = $this->get_upload_path($file_name, $version);
                if (is_file($file)) {
                    $this->delete_img($file_name);
                    unlink($file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->generate_response(array('success' => $success), $print_response);
}
}
```

I can make the pictures upload with no db but in this case drowning me for hours. Please get me out of here.